# Excel table data transpose

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel table in the following format that contains data for a process

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs86A.png)

I want the data to be transformed from the input model to the output model. My actual data contains 22 process and 6 sub-processes with 16,000 Unique IDs. Thus manual transformation is not possible. Please suggest an algorithm that I can replicate on a large scale.

Comment: Hi @MavRage this can't achieve using TRANSPOSE,, need Formula, please [edit] your post & share the method/Formula you have tried so far !!

Comment: Hi @rajeshS, I have not been able to achieve this yet. I have only made a small sample table for what I want to achieve. Sample transformation has been done by copy/paste to describe the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

For large reshape operations which are repeatable as the input data grows, I recommend PowerQuery instead of formulas.

Select a cell in your input range.

Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range to create a power query on your input range.

[image]

Select the columns 'Unique ID' and 'Attribute' then use Transform>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot other columns to get this:

[image]

Select 'Attribute.1', right-click and use Split Column>By Non-Digit to Digit, to get this:

[image]

Select 'Attribute.1.2' and use Transform>Pivot Column. Use Attribute.1.2 as the column to pivot by and Value as the Values column. When you do this, the cells of the table will contain numbers, and not your text values.

To correct that, go to Home>Advanced Editor and replace where it says `List.Count` with `List.First`:

[image]

After that change, you will have the data in the required format. You can re-order the columns by dragging them to the desired position and rename them as you wish, then use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the spreadsheet.

[image]

Here is the full text from my Advanced Editor, for reference:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Unique ID", type text}, {"Attribute", type text}, {"A1", type text}, {"A2", type text}, {"A3", type text}, {"B1", type text}, {"B2", type text}, {"B3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Unique ID", "Attribute"}, "Attribute.1", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute.1", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Attribute.1.1", "Attribute.1.2"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Character Transition", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Character Transition"[Attribute.1.2]), "Attribute.1.2", "Value", List.First),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Attribute.1.1", "Unique ID", "Attribute", "1", "2", "3"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Attribute.1.1", "Step"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```